# Xcode6 Swift add Remote Push Notifications and send from PHP

Tags: swift, push-notification, xcode6

I want to send Push Notifications via a PHP script to all app users. About Google Unfortunately there are no tutorials for Push Notifications with Swift. Parse.com I do not want to use. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Swift or php? Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I want to send Push Notifications from PHP Script to my IOS App. Sorry I can´t try anything, because i found only Objective-C Tutorials and i need Swift.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on sending push notifications using php.

Comment: Yes php and Xcode objective-c but not php and Xcode Swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK now it works ! (:

Create Certificate for APN:
[raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Swift Code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

    var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()



    return true

}



func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    println(deviceToken)

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

    println(error)

}
```

find the deviceToken in the Xcode Console

PHP Script

use the PHP Script from here [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) (scroll down)

run the PHP Script and viola (: